# Import Python Functions from Auto-Running Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a python DES script that ends in a call to main().  That runs the main menu and starts the DES process.  I would like to run analytics on my DES functions with another script.  Whenever I do something like `from DES.py import des` to try to avoid having main run, it still starts anyway.  **How do I import the functions and keep the trailing reference to main from being called?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `import` a module in Python, you execute the code in that module.  So if your module looks like this:

```
def main():
  print 'Hello, world.'

main()
```

Then every time you import your module, it will execute the call to
`main()`.  To prevent this from happening, you can look at the special
variable `__name__`, which is set to `__main__` in the main program --
the thing that was directly started by the interpreter.  When you
`import` a module, `__name__` is set to something else (generally, the
name of the module).  If you want to have code that is run when
directly executing your module (`python mymodule.py`) but is ignored
when importing your module (`import mymodule`), then you can check the
value of the `__name__` variable:

```
def main():
  print 'Hello, world.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The above code will execute `main()` when run directly, but will not
when imported.